# How to use .wav file of 4 seconds to play tones in it based on progressbar value [0-250] range in c#

Tags: c#, audio, wav

I have a .wav file of 5 seconds of a diagonal sound [0 sec - low pitch and 4 sec - high pitch]. I want to extract tones from this .wav file and play it to alert user for speed control along with a progress bar value of range [0 - 250] values.

So If speed value = 0 then progress bar is empty and tone from .wav should at low pitch [0 sec]. If speed value = 10 then progress bar value is 10 and tone from .wav should be slightly higher in pitch [say 0.10 sec]. If speed value = 20 then progress bar value is 20 and tone from .wav should be slightly higher in pitch [say 0.20 sec] and so on till speed value = 250 then progress bar value is 250 and tone from .wav should be at highest in pitch [say 4 sec]

I'm new to such media extraction of tones from .wav and play it in c# based on progress bar value. Please guide me thru the process.

I tried to convert .wav file in byte array streams by using .wav cutter. But didn't under stood to play it continuous based on progress bar value. Please help me with a better implementation logic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WAV files contain PCM audio, which means each sample is a measurement of pressure level for that moment in time.  Suppose you had 5 seconds of a sine wave at 1kHz, sampled at 44.1kHz (standard sampling rate for CD audio), and you wanted to stretch out playback of those 5 seconds to 10 seconds.  If you simply play back those samples slower so that the WAV file lasts longer, you effectively lower the audible pitch by one octave, down to 500Hz, while cutting the sample rate in half, down to 22.05kHz.  Take this example and think about your WAV of a frequency sweep.  Even if you knew how long it had to playback ahead of time, all you do is change the pitch and length of the sweep.  This isn't really what you want to do.

You are asking to keep the pitch the same, but vary the time.  To do this, you would have to convert your PCM audio from the time-domain to the frequency-domain.  A Fourier Transform (implemented as FFT in software) does this.  This is pretty much how MP3s work.  Basically, instead of measuring the waveform through its peaks and valleys, you measure the level of various frequency bands, and play them back for a short period of time, usually around 8ms.  In any case, this is likely a huge hassle for what you need to do.

I suggest simply generating the frequency sweep yourself, as the progress bar goes up.  Generate a simple sine wave, and as the progress bar increases, so does the frequency of sine wave you are generating.  Much simpler.